# Rails performance tests "rake test:benchmark" and "rake test:profile" give me errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance-testing

I'm trying to run a blank default performance test with Ruby 1.9 and Rails 2.3.5 and I just can't get it to work!  What am I missing here???

```
rails testapp
cd testapp
script/generate scaffold User name:string
rake db:migrate
rake test:benchmark
```

-

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby19 -I"lib:test" "/usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/performance/browsing_test.rb" -- --benchmark
Loaded suite /usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:105:in `rescue in const_missing': uninitialized constant BrowsingTest::STARTED (NameError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:94:in `const_missing'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby19/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/testing/performance.rb:38:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby19/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:415:in `block (2 levels) in run_test_suites'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby19/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:409:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby19/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:409:in `block in run_test_suites'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby19/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:408:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby19/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:408:in `run_test_suites'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby19/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:388:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby19/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:329:in `block in autorun'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/bin/ruby19 -I"lib:test" "/usr/l...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4171-fresh-rails-3-app-cannot-run-performance-tests).
For a patch, see [here](http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/835f5d0269a8d3615585119e77f1ba7d601c943b#diff-1).

Comment: The referenced patch doesn't really fix the problem for me.  I'm running Ruby 1.9.2, and I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 9):

OK, the problem is that ruby 1.8 used Test::Unit as its default testing library.  In ruby 1.9 that got changed to MiniTest.

Versions of ActiveSupport prior to 3.1.0 assumed Test::Unit.  It looks like it has been addressed in 3.1.0 and later.  If you're using rails 3.0.9 though, it has a dependency on activesupport 3.0.9, so you can't ask for later versions in your Gemfile.

Found [this](http://jamesmead.org/blog/2009-02-02-test-unit-and-minitest-with-different-ruby-versions) via Google.  Apparently, the Test::Unit library is still available, but as a gem named 'test-unit'.

So in my Gemfile at the top before the rails gem, I put:

```
gem 'test-unit', '~> 2.3.0'
```

Then I ran rake test:benchmark and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a bug. I am able to run the code with ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [universal-darwin9.0]. Under Ruby 1.9.1, I get an exception like the one you describe.

When it reaches ActiveSupport::Testing::Performance#run (in rails) it causes an exception at the line `yield(self.class::STARTED, name)` where it tries to find the constant ::START. Ruby Prof has a similar method too, under RubyProf::Test#run.

I don't know who's at fault here.